# Robocopy - enable data validation?

Tags: robocopy

I am copying a file using robocopy, however I have noticed that the destination file is always corrupted, is there an option with robocopy I can use to ensure that each chunk is validated during the transfer? using 7zip, I can see that the checksums do not match after transfer has completed.

Answer (score 1):

Robocopy does not contain this feature.

Instead of robocopy you could either use rsync, teracopy etc. or you could validate the files in a second step after the backup is finished and restart the job if the files are not valid.

If this backup is just running through your internal network, independent of your decision, you should try to find the source of the data corruption. Possibly there is a corrupt harddrive, something is wrong on the network etc..

Answer (score 0):

That feature is not supported. 
For larger files with included CRC-check use something like 
[TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy).